# Show $gLg^{-1} \cap L = \{1\}$ for all $g \notin L$ where $G = N \rtimes L$ and for all $n \neq 1$ in N, $C_{G}(n) \subseteq N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

I’m currently studying for an exam and I was working on the problem below:

> Let $G$ be a finite semidirect product group $N \rtimes L$, where $N$ is normal. Assume $L$ nontrivial, and for all $n \neq 1$ in $N$, $C_{G}(n) \subseteq N$. Then, prove $gLg^{-1} \cap L = \{1\}$ for all $g \notin L$ and furthermore, prove gcd$(|L|,|N|)=1$.

I was able to get started on the first part but wasn’t able to go much further. I will show my work up until I got stuck below.

**Proof.** First, assume $\phi$ is the homomorphism associated to $G = N \rtimes L$. Thus, $\phi: L \to Aut(N)$ and, furthermore, $\phi_l: N \to N$ is an automorphism for all $l \in L$.

Now, let $g = (a,b) \in G$ such that $(a,b) \notin L$. Then, $a \neq 1$. Now, let $(x,y) \in gLg^{-1} \cap L$. Hence, $(x,y) \in gLg^{-1}$ and $(x,y) \in L$. Thus, $x = 1$. So, $(1,y) \in gLg^{-1} = g^{-1}Lg$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
(1,y) =&(a,b)^{-1}(1,l)(a,b)\\
=&(\phi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}),b^{-1})(1,l)(a,b)\\
=&(\phi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}) \phi_{b^{-1}}(1),b^{-1}l)(a,b)\\
=&(\phi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}),b^{-1}l)(a,b)\\
=&(\phi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}) \phi_{b^{-1}l}(a),b^{-1}lb)\\
=&(\phi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}\phi_l(a)),b^{-1}lb).
\end{align*}

Consequently, $\phi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}\phi_l(a)) = 1$ which implies $a^{-1}\phi_l(a) = 1$. Thus, $\phi_l(a)=a$. Since $a$ is arbitrary, $l \in$ ker($\phi$).

Now, this is where I am stuck. The only way for my proof to go forward is for ker($\phi$) $=\{1\}$. However, I believe that I am unable to really say anything about $\phi$ other than it is a homomorphism. I’m not sure how to prove $\phi$ is injective, which is how we would get ker($\phi$) $=\{1\}$, if that is what I should be going for. We also have that $C_G(n) \subseteq N$ for all nontrivial $n \in N$ but I don’t know where or how to use that in this problem.

Furthermore, I am just not sure how to even approach the second half of this problem in general either. I’ve been working on this for about a day and a half or so and would really like to know what I am missing so I can study more for my exam.

Thank you so much ahead of time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need to use $C_G(n) \subset N$ to prove $\phi$ is injective, e.g. if $G$ is the direct product and $\phi$ is trivial. Can you show if $l$ is in the kernel of $\phi$, then $(1, l)$ commutes with an element of $N$?

Comment: @jacob Thanks! That was the observation I kept looking over! For some reason, I kept thinking (1,l)(n,1) = (n,l) for all l, and that’s not the case! I was able to solve the first proof with this comment then.

Comment: My hint for the second part is to use orbit-stabilizer. let me know if you want more hints than that

Comment: @jacob So, I would like another hint, if you could. I know that L acts on N via $\phi$. Maybe we could use the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, but I am unsure how that would imply that |L| and |N| are coprime.

Comment: Try looking at the orbits of the elements of $N$. There is a trivial orbit which just has the identity element of $N$. For $n \neq 1$, what are $stab(n)$ and $orbit(n)$? Once you find that, try writing $N$ as the disjoint union of all of the orbits.

Comment: Again you will have to use that fact that $C_G(n) \subset N$, as you can certainly take a direct product of two groups whose orders are not coprime.